# Redefine __init__ of a subclass to take different parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, initialization

```
class Date(datetime.date):

    def __init__self(self, year, month, day):
        super().__init__(year, month, day)
```

Suppose I create such a class that inherits from `datetime.date` and I want to redefine the `__init__` method so instead of taking arguments `year`, `month` and `day`, to take a string `s`, to parse it and pass the parsed variables in the super `__init__` method. Something like this:

```
class Date(datetime.date):

    def __init__self(self, s):
       args = self.parse(s)
       super().__init__(*args)
```

Is this practice correct and what I mean is this used in practice?

Comment: there's already a function that will do that just as easily : `dateimte.datetime.strptime`, why would you want to subclass Date when the functionality is already there? if that is the only reason for you to subclass then subclassing is meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can do it. But according to [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), the ancestor's interface should resemble its parent's one (but ancestor's interface can be wider). In your case class taking `s` as parameter cannot be used in context where `year`, `month` and `day` are passed. So this approach is not very good.

Nevertheless you can achieve this if you make ancestor's constructor more complex:

```
class Date(datetime.date):
    def __init__self(self, year=None, month=None, day=None, s=None):
       if s is None:
           args = year, month, day
       else:
           args = self.parse(s)
       super().__init__(*args)
```

But as for me, I'd keep things simple and implement something like this:

```
class Date(datetime.date):
    def __init__self(self, year, month, day):
        super().__init__(year, month, day)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, s):
       args = ...
       return cls(*args)
```

(As @Mike Housky already mentioned, such a trivial constructor can be omitted; I wrote it just to make my example clearer)

Answer (score 0):

The call to the base class `__init__` method is both correct and necessary.  Python will only call the superclass `__init__` method if the subclass doesn't have one.

Python will let you omit that `super().__init__` call, but that will leave the superclass uninitialized.  That's not really inheritance. Or, maybe it's not really OOP since you're assuming that inherited methods will work without the base class's `__init__` being called, and that breaks encapsulation.  Either way, it's not OOP.

It's also quite common to pass different arguments to the superclass `__init__()` method.  The subclass often needs additional information.

What's fishy in your example is the call to `self.parse()` before the the object has been fully initialized.  If that's your own method, to be defined later in the `Date` class, it should probably be a class method, rather than an instance method.  If it's an instance method inherited from `datetime.date` then you have no guarantee that it will work.